# HTML: Why is my dropdown menu expanding?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, nav

I'm playing around with some HTML5 and CSS3 and trying to build a single static page for now.
Currently working on the navigation menu with one of the items being a drop down menu.
When I hover above the drop down item, the item is pushing the items on its left and right away.

Could someone explain to me why this is happening? I have very little HTML or CSS experience, I just started putting something together.

The CSS is based on many tutorials on the internet for making drop down navigation menu's. I've stripped most of the code down to the "very basic" to get this working.

Edit: Any tips to make the CSS cleaner are welcome as well.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav role="navigation" class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        Content
    </div>
    <footer>
        Footer
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 1em !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300;
}

body {
    background-color: #646464;
}

header {
    background-color: #444;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    height: 2.55556em;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 70%;
}

footer {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: white;
}

nav {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}

nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
}

nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that your secondary menu UL is wider than your primary menu LI containing it. When the embedded UL switches from display:none to display:block it increases the width of the parent LI.

A couple possible solutions:
specify a width for your main menu LIs, e.g.:

```
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Use position: absolute to take the embedded UL out of the layout flow, e.g.:

```
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Both of these options have some issues with your current layout, though, and would required you to rework things a bit. Hopefully this is helpful in terms of pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try by like bellow:

```
nav>ul { display: inline-block; list-style: none; }
```

Comment: its the first ul style, after try, inform me.

Comment: Doesn't work. It's still pushing the items away for a few pixels.